# How can use external library in ros

Tags: ros, library, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use POCO library within my package.
I followed this manual http://wiki.ros.org/UsingThirdPartyLibraries
but it was not successful.

I tried to add
find_package(poco REQUIRED)
to CMakeLists.txt but cmake can't find it.

Would you please help me to add POCO to my project.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189788/how-can-use-external-library-in-ros./) by [pjnsoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/19994/pjnsoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-12**:
Maybe it might be a good idea to find out if what you'd like to do is handled by http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [class_loader](https://github.com/ros/class_loader) package uses Poco. Perhaps you can use it as a template?

It looks like they have a cmake directory and a PocoConfig.cmake which describes where to find the Poco libraries, and a dependency on libpoco-dev in their package.xml

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3